Can you run 6/3 wire 250 feet?
Can you run 6/3 wire 250 feet and not lose voltage?

30 or 40 amps should not lose any voltage to matter.  The full 50 amps allowed will lose a bit of voltage, but probably with in limits(3% to 5%)

You wouldn't run copper wire over such a long distance.  You would run 2-2-2-4 MH feeder if outdoors/underground, or SER if indoors. The extra large size of these wires usually takes care of the voltage drop for you. These conductors are aluminum but are safe at such large sizes. The wires will land on lugs which are aluminum rated and made of aluminum. Why create a dissimilar metal problem? But your question is unclear.  We'll have very different advice if this is an RV stand vs if this is EV charging.

It all depends on voltage (120V vs. 240V), current and cable/wire type.
There are formulas available, but the simplest thing to do is to use an online calculator. For example:

6 AWG copper at 240V and 44A (maximum continuous value allowed based on 80% of 55A maximum for NM-B or UF-B cable) has a 4.05% voltage drop
6 AWG copper at 120V and 30A has a much larger 5.52% voltage drop. Note however that most 6 AWG circuits are either entirely or primarily 240V, unless powering a subpanel of mixed loads.
6 AWG copper at 240V and 55A (maximum circuit size) has a 5.06% drop

And there are numerous other possible variations. So it really depends on the specific use case. Also keep in mind that aluminum may be a good option as aluminum is generally much less expensive at large sizes than copper. You can likely use a much larger size (e.g., 2 AWG, rated for 90A) aluminum for a lot lower cost than 6 AWG copper and have much lower voltage drop.
In most places, the "3% maximum drop" is a guideline and not a hard and fast rule. Using the examples above but switching to 2 AWG aluminum:

240V and 44A = 2.69%
120V and 30A  = 3.67%
240V and 55A = 3.36%

